# benefit of a viewcontroller in monotouch / iphone App

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

I see alot of view controllers used, and I wondered why it isnt more common to just use views instead i.e.

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        window.AddSubview(myMasterView);   // or controller.View
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();        
        return true;
    }
```

and then switch subviews in and out of the masterview. If I dont use any Navigation GUI, then is it more efficient to just have Views? Do ViewControllers help with GC better?

thanks

Comment: VCs don't seem to add much overhead in my experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ViewControllers just happen to hook up by default to a number of interesting system notifications like rotation.   So they turn those notifications into method calls that you could override.

But if you want to do things on your own, you certainly can.